# Where can I find task duration (estimate) data?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, programming, education

## Scenario

In an endeavour to compare a basic regression with a more advanced Ensemble Network of classifiers, I am looking for (a) data(set) that contains:

- Task description
- Measured task duration
- (Estimated task duration prior to starting task)

## Attempts

I have built a scraper that analyzes the taskwarrior data pushed to public githubs, yielding 219607 [tasks- and task edits], of which 61284 unique tasks/task edits, of which 5105 unique tasks, of which 159 contain a start and completion date.

Furthermore I have contacted the authors of the [study using a 2.6 million sample task duration database from Cortana](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/01/TaskDuration-WSDM2019.pdf) and the [study using a task database from 1989 consisting of 16000 tasks](http://ieg.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/~aigner/projects/planninglines/evaluation/Project_Management/papers/hill99taskduration.pdf). The former is a propriatary dataset which I am currently not able to access, the latter has been lost by whom I was able to contact.

## Question

Do you have any suggestions on where I can find a (large,5k+) dataset that contains task description and task duration information?

---

Comment: Is there any new news on such a dataset.